# R: matching rows from two data frames with smallest time gap

Tags: r, time, match

Given two data frames, for each row in the first data frame, find the row with the same `product_id`, but `visiting_time` is larger, and the time gap of visting time between the two rows are smallest.

**For example**

the 2th row of cart_add_data is matched with the first row of `purchase_data`.

BTW, the computing effciency is also important.

**data frame:** `cart_add_data`

```
    visting_time           product_id
 1  2012-01-08 13:29:39    878435
 2  2012-01-08 13:36:52    122100
 3  2012-01-08 13:38:47    150473
 4  2012-01-14 21:06:36    169403
 5  2012-01-14 21:06:36    137092
```

**data frame:** `purchase_data`

```
    visting_time            product_id
 1  2012-01-08 13:42:35     122100 
 2  2012-01-08 13:42:35     138857 
 3  2012-01-08 13:42:35     150473 
 4  2012-01-18 22:15:04     140376 
 5  2012-02-02 09:21:28     130437
```

Comment: What is the threshold ?

Comment: no threshold, if there are multiple matched rows, only keep the row with smallest time gap. If there is only one matched row, then keep it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you want (?) (I added a couple of rows to match your other criteria:

```
cart_add_data <- read.csv(text="visting_time,           product_id
 2012-01-08 13:29:39,    878435
 2012-01-08 13:36:52,    122100
 2012-01-08 13:38:47,    150473
 2012-01-14 21:06:36,    169403
 2012-01-14 21:06:36,    137092")

purchase_data <- read.csv(text="    visting_time,           product_id
2012-01-08 13:42:35,     122100 
2012-01-08 13:42:35,     138857 
2012-01-08 13:42:35,     150473 
2012-01-18 22:15:04,     140376 
2012-02-02 09:21:28,     130437
2012-01-14 12:06:36,    137092
2012-01-14 22:06:36,    137092
2012-01-14 23:06:36,    137092")

dfr <- merge(cart_add_data, purchase_data, by="product_id")

dfr$time_dif <- with(dfr, as.numeric(as.POSIXct(visting_time.y) - as.POSIXct(visting_time.x)))

dfr <- subset(dfr, time_dif > 0)
dfr <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dfr,dfr$product_id),
                          function(x)x[which.min(x$time_dif),]))
```